# Azure webapp security group access

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

I have an azure web app which I want to restrict the access to its URL and allow access exclusively through my application gateway. One of the option is to use "Access Restriction" but I would like to achieve this using the security group as will give me more freedom and customisation as I have a lot of app services.

Using terraform I configured the application gateway, app gateway subnet and the app service gateway as follow

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "VNET" {
  address_space       = ["VNET-CIDR"]
  location            = var.location
  name                = "hri-prd-VNET"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-hri-prd-eur-app-gate.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "app-gate" {
  name                 = "app-gateway-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.app-gate.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.VNET.name
  address_prefixes     = ["SUBNET-CIDR"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "app-service" {
  name                 = "app-service-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.app-gate.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.hri-prd-VNET.name
  address_prefixes     = ["APP_CIDR"]
  delegation {
    name = "app-service-delegation"
    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}
```

while in my security group I configured the mapping as follow:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "app-service-sg" {
  location            = var.app-service-loc
  name                = "app-service-sg"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.app-service.name
  security_rule {
    access = "Allow"
    direction = "Inbound"
    name = "application_gateway_access"
    priority = 100
    protocol = "Tcp"
    destination_port_range = "80"
    source_port_range = "*"
    source_address_prefixes = ["app-gate-CIDR"]
    destination_address_prefixes = ["app-service-CIDR"]

  }

}


resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "app-service-assoc" {
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.app-service-sg.id
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.app-service.id
}
```

The configuration runs without any issue with terraform, but when I hit the web app url directly I am able to access it.

What am I doing wrong at this stage? because I would like to be able to reach the web app url only though my application gateway.

Thank you so much for any help guys

Answer (score 1):

You have just created networks and security groups. You need to use Application Gateway integration with service endpoints

Additionally you will need to make further configuration.
Here is a diagram how your solution should look like.
[image: ![enter image description here]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/app-gateway-with-service-endpoints

Create App Service using Terraform code and add IP restrictions.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service#ip_restriction

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "example-app-service-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  name                = "example-app-service"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
site_config {
    ip_restriction {
      ip_address  = "0.0.0.0"
    }
}
```

Link App Service to your Network

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "example" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_app_service.example.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.app-service.id
}
```

Create the access restriction using service endpoints.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#set-a-service-endpoint-based-rule

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the access restrictions? to do it all through subnets and azure security groups?

Comment: No. There was actually no way to do this until the introduction of service endpoints in 2019.